# Does "locally connected and path-connected" imply locally path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Some friends and I discovered this question when we were studying for an exam and were trying to find examples for all combinations of topological properties we had seen in the course so far. 
One we couldn't answer was, if there is a space that has the three properties: 

-it is  locally connected

-it is pathwise connected

-it is NOT locally pathwise connected

Even after looking at several books and asking our professor, we could neither find an example nor prove that such a space cannot exist.

 Does anybody know something about this?

Edit: "Counterexamples in Topology" was among the books, but while I spent some time searching through it, I cannot exclude the possibility to have missed just the right space.

Comment: Was "Counterexamples in topology" among the sevreral boos?

Comment: Next time, you could use http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146
It's a searchable database of the counterexamples that you can find in the book. Unafortunately, this time, your counterexample was not known...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_%28topology%29) on [$\mathbb{R}_{cocountable}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) should work.