# Prove that any open connected subset of $\mathbb R^m$ is path-connected.

Tags: connectedness, path-connected

> > $\forall S \subseteq \mathbb R^m, (S:\text{Connected}\land S:\text{Open in } \mathbb R^m \to S: \text{Path Connected})$

I searched on this website, and I could only find two proofs.

The first proof uses the concept of locally path connectedness, but I do not know this.

About [the other proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219540), I cannot understand the second paragraph.

> > Let $x\in A$ (hence not empty); suppose $\exists \varepsilon >0 : B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. Since open balls are convex, it is path connected. Thus for any point $y$ in $B(x)$, there is a path from $x$ to $y$. Since $A$ is a set of points in $U$ that can join $a$, then there exist a path between $x$ and $a$. Since there is a path from $y$ to $x$ and $x$ to $a$; then, there is a path from $y$ to $a$ implying $y$ is in $A$. Since $y\in B(x,\varepsilon)$, we conclude $B(x) \subseteq A$, hence $A$ is open

Could you provide the easy proof?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219540/connected-open-subsets-in-mathbbr2-are-path-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: What *exactly* don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the basic fact that is mentioned that if there is a path from $x$ to $y$ and another path from $y$ to $z$ we can construct a combined path from $x$ to $z$? That is the main idea, plus that we have a (straight line) path from the centre of a ball to any of its points, by convexity of balls.

Comment: Because of your comment, I finally could understand the second paragraph!! I totally understand now. Thank you so much!