# Locally connected but not connected and not locally path connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected, locally-connected

I'm looking for a topological space locally connected but not connected and not locally path connected. Is there any space with this properties? I haven't been able to find one

Comment: Does this question help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843173/path-connected-and-locally-connected-space-that-is-not-locally-path-connected Space 4 is what you're looking for I believe

Comment: Especially [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1499512/4280) for the long  circle.